# Vertical alignment of Label inside TextBlock is wrong

Tags: wpf, xaml, layout, data-binding

In a WPF popup window that I display to the user I want to put a text that is bound to a variable inside a block of text.
I've tried to do so by putting a `<Label>` inside a `<TextBlock>`.
However, this leads to alignment problems, see markup and picture below.
I wonder how I can get the text in the `Label` to align vertically with the text in the `TextBlock`, or if there is a better solution?

I could put the entire text in a variable, but then I don't know how to get `<Bold>` formatting for part of the text.

```
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap"
 VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="99" Width="339" Grid.RowSpan="3">
    The user is <Bold>responsible</Bold> for 
    <Bold><Label Content="00" Padding="0"/></Bold> vehicles
</TextBlock>
```

[image: Wrong alignment of label inside TextBlock.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.run?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) inline element for data binding text.

> Starting in the .NET Framework 4, the Text property of the Run object is a dependency property, which means that you can bind the Text property to a data source.

It also has properties for styling the text, like `FontWeight`, no need for `<Bold>` here.

```
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap"
 VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="99" Width="339" Grid.RowSpan="3">
    The user is <Bold>responsible</Bold> for 
    <Run Text="{Binding YourProperty}" FontWeight="Bold"/> vehicles
</TextBlock>
```

The result looks like this:

[image: Text with databound run.]

---

As a general note on the issue: The elements inside `TextBlock` should be [inline elements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.inline?view=windowsdesktop-6.0). Here is an article that has links to other inline elements that could be useful to you, like [`span`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.span?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) that allows for grouping other inline elements and applying styles or to them.

- [How to: Manipulate Flow Content Elements through the Inlines Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/how-to-manipulate-flow-content-elements-through-the-inlines-property?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

WPF has two fundamental base types, `UIElement` and `ContentElement`. While a `TextBlock` and `Label` are `UIElement`s, the content of `TextBlock` are inlines, which are `ContentElements`. That is why the alignment is off, they serve very different purposes. You can read up more on the differences and concepts here:

- [Base Element APIs in WPF Classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/base-elements-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#base-element-apis-in-wpf-classes)
- [UIElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)

  > `UIElement` is a base class for WPF core level implementations building on Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) elements and basic presentation characteristics.
- [ContentElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.contentelement?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)

  > Provides a WPF core-level base class for content elements. Content elements are designed for flow-style presentation, using an intuitive markup-oriented layout model and a deliberately simple object model.
- [Flow Document Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/flow-document-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Comment: excellent, thanks! Also thanks for your explanation of the different types of elements. I'm fairly new to WPF. Some WPF concepts are much like html, but sometimes the similarities are only confusing